# User keeps getting a 'Access Required' page

Tags: sharepoint-online, access

I've got an external user who has had access to a SharePoint 2016 site before. He couldn't get in today and keeps getting the 'Access required' no matter how many times i send him a Sharing Request add him to the groups or Approve his requests he keeps coming back to the "Access Required" page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could go to user inormation list, delete the external user there. Then add the user in the groups again.

The url of user information list:
https://yoursites/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0

Comment: Ahhhh, he's not in that list so that could be the issue?

Comment: So if a user wasn't in that group they would be able to gain access or would continue to get the Access request page?

Comment: If a user isn't in the user information list, he do not have access to the site. When you grant a user permssions, the user would be added to the user information list automatically.

Comment: Thanks Michael. What could be causing the list not to be updated and is there a way I could manually add users?

Comment: You could go to site settings-> site permissions, give this user permissions manually.

Comment: Thanks Michael, yes already done that and he still gets the Access Request page and doesn't show up in the Information List. I've escalated it to our Infrastructure Team I don't know what could be causing it.